# Failure in creating service when using "topologySpreadConstraints" in Deployment definition

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, minikube, kubernetes-deployment

We are running an application inside a cluster we created in GKE. We have created required yamls (consisting of Service and Deployment definition). We recently have decided to use Pod Topology for that I have added following piece in my Deployment yaml file under spec section-

```
 spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: node
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        app: foo-app
```

This change is working as expected when I am running the service inside a minikube cluster while the same change is not working inside a GKE cluster. It throws an error-

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): unknown field "topologySpreadConstraints" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec
```

I searched a lot but could not find a satisfactory answer. Has anybody faced this problem? Please help me understand the problem and its resolution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what version of k8s is present in GKE ?

Comment: Got it. Client version was perfect (1.18.6) while server version was something which was causing problem. I upgraded that and it worked. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are running `1.17.7-gke.17` on your GKE cluster. Unfortunately this is the latest version you can upgrade to, through the [rapid channel](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes-rapid), at the time of this post.

`topologySpreadConstraints` is available in Kubernetes v1.18 [FEATURE STATE: [beta]](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/)

Comment: Thanks Neo. I had to upgrade Server version (Client version was perfect `1.18.6`) and it worked.